# Send email when you publish a new article

Tags: plone

I was able to find the function that sends an email every time a new item is created. Unfortunately I lost my notes and I can not find this feature more. Remember, that you entered the menu zope them and outlined a function to the occurrence of an event ..... can you help? Sorry for the bad English,

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to use a Plone native feature: content rules.

Go the the "content rule" section of your Plone control panel (`http://yoursite/@@rules-controlpanel`) then configure a rule with a "mailer" action. The trigger action could be a workflow transition change.

Comment: as they say: "rules, rulez!" ;)